# Why do I need to use a lookless control instead of a UserControl when I have swappable sub-parts

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with some custom controls (defined inside the same project) that have swappable sub parts. As a basic example, lets says I have some Xaml like:

```
<Border Background="White" CornerRadius="9">
    <ContentPresenter/>
</Border>
```

Which is used for my class derived from `ContentControl`, lets call it `MrWhiteControl`

If I make `MrWhiteControl` a xaml and code-behind file pair (so it has an `InitializeComponent()` call in the ctor), then whatever I place in the `Content` property has lots of problems e.g. the `DataContext` won't inherit properly, and using `ElementName` in bindings won't work.

However, if I use a [lookless control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37326/Lookless-Controls-Themes) - so a MrWhiteControl.cs file with the style defined in Themes/Generic.xaml (I don't care about theming support in this app) - then everything works fine.

What I want to know is why this is the case. What's going on behind the scenes that means the lookless control works fine, but that the xaml with code-behind doesn't work properly?

I've created an [example project you can clone from GitHub](https://github.com/WilkaH/StackoverflowQuestion-22712206). If you run that, you'll see that the `ElementName` binding doesn't work inside the control that has a code-behind (2nd in the list), but does work fine with the lookless control (bottom of the list).

What difference is there between lookless and user controls hosting a content presenter?

Comment: Give an examples: nonworking example and working example.

Comment: Good point @Anatoliy, I've added one now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Added a solution to get the binding to work with this approach at the bottom.

---

Nice question.

AFAICT this is just because of the way the DP is setup and when the Binding is resolved respecting NameScope's.

From `MainWindow.xaml` you're assigning the DP `MyContent` property for the control with code-behind which takes the entire `TextBox` code as the DP value. Hence the binding is not resolved at this point.

When the Binding is applied, in the scope of the UserControl, the ElementName is not found, which we can verify if we add another `TextBox` into that `UserControl`, say

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Name="textBox" Text="Sampleeeeeeee" />
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type LookslessVsUserControl:MrWhiteWithCodeBehind}}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now we get

[image]

as the point the Binding is resolved the new `TextBox` is the one which is in scope not the one from MainWindow.xaml

As for the `Style`, the scope remains the same where the `Style` is applied, so it finds the MainWindow.xaml's text-box. We hence only have the one level of nesting, which we can also see from Snoop

[image]

**Solution:**

If this is the approach you prefer to set the DP with the control, you can still get the Binding to work:

In your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` you need to set the namescope for the `UserControl` accordingly so it doesn't use it's own [WPF Xaml NameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx)

In `ctor()` `of MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
Loaded += (sender, args) => NameScope.SetNameScope(problemControl, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

and in xaml I named it `problemControl` such as:

```
<LookslessVsUserControl:MrWhiteWithCodeBehind x:Name="problemControl">
  <LookslessVsUserControl:MrWhiteWithCodeBehind.MyContent>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text}" />
  </LookslessVsUserControl:MrWhiteWithCodeBehind.MyContent>
</LookslessVsUserControl:MrWhiteWithCodeBehind>
```

With this when the `UserControl` loads and tries to resolve the `Binding` it should find the `TextBox` fine and give you the output you desire.